# Can I make any format mask I like for datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

Given a date and time in a specific format can I use datetime with a format mask that suits to read in the values, when the values aren't all that typical? For example how would I create a mask that works with the following:

```
08264.51782528
08 = last 2 digits of year (will be within  last 60 years so if the 2 digits are above current (eg. 18, then assume they're in the 20th century)
264 = number of days
51782528 = decimal representation of how far through the day (0 = midnight, 0.5 = noon, 0.999988 = 1 second to midnight the following day)
```

Comment: Would a year value of `18` not better be put in the 21st century? That way it will be interpreted as `2018`, not `1918`. (Of course it entirely depends on what these dates are for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into timedelta.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# get year, day, and day_percent
if year >= 58:
    year += 1900
else:
    year += 2000
date = datetime(year, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=day-1) + (timedelta(days=1) * day_percent)
```

This assumes day 1 is the first day of the year (January 1st).